# <link rel="preload" has an unsupported `type` value (fonts preload)

Tags: google-chrome, font-face, preloading

The following from Mozilla's web docs [Preloading content with rel="preload"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) results in errors in chrome regarding the link type:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web font example</title>

  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.eot" as="font" type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.svg" as="font" type="image/svg+xml" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/zantroke-webfont.eot" as="font" type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/zantroke-webfont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/zantroke-webfont.woff" as="font" type="font/woff" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/zantroke-webfont.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="preload" href="fonts/zantroke-webfont.svg" as="font" type="image/svg+xml" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You can see the full [example source code on GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/html-examples/tree/master/link-rel-preload/fonts) ([also see it live](https://mdn.github.io/html-examples/link-rel-preload/fonts/))

Here us a screenshot of the live link:
[image]

It seems these are the unsupported types that error out:

```
type="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"
type="image/svg+xml"
```

How can I get rid of that error in console for those webfont types? The types are as is from their example. I know I can physically hide the error via filters to not show in console, but I really want to prevent it from showing in the first place using a correct solution.

Comment: Does changing your `as` attributes to `application` and `image` respectively make any difference?

Comment: I changed them respectively, but no difference.

Comment: it is a warning not an error. According to the spec this is backwards compatible because the ressource will still be loaded when needed (but a bit later)

Answer (score 4):

follow w3c about [preload](https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/), you can remove `type` in preload tag
ex:

```
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.eot" as="font" crossorigin>
<link rel="preload" href="fonts/cicle_fina-webfont.svg" as="image" crossorigin>
```

Answer (score 1):

.eot fonts aren't supported in Chrome, see:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=eot